# I need to turn my python 3.6.1 script into .EXE file. How do I do that?

Tags: exe, pyinstaller, py2exe, cx-freeze, python-3.6

I have seen 10's of tutorial for python to exe. very few are for 3.6.1 and none have worked for me.
Please help.

Gabriel

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing that works well for python 3.6, so use python 3.5. When I convert python scripts to exe I use PyInstaller3.2.1 https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyInstaller/3.2.1
and it works fine. Make sure your script is in the pyinstaller folder after you have built it then run the command `python pyinstaller.py scriptName.py`

Comment: pyinstaller didn't work in my case. see my post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45750676/build-a-exe-for-windows-from-a-python-3-script-importing-pyqtgraph-and-opening. it seems pyinstaller shows paradoxical properties: on one side it is not compatible with python 3.6; on the other side some syntax behaviors like my 'yield' problem seems to be linked to asynchronous generators that are not compatible with python 3.5-...

Answer (score 0):

cx-freeze is working with Python 3.6 - At least I already created binaries with this combination.

Here is a description of how to use it: https://regilanj.wordpress.com/2017/06/07/py-to-exe-in-python-3-6-1/

Comment: cx-freeze didn't work in my case, see my post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45734926/build-a-exe-for-windows-from-a-python-3-script-importing-pyqtgraph-and-opening