# py2exe help - missing modules

Tags: python, numpy, py2exe

I am new to using Py2Exe and I am struggling a bit with the errors it is throwing up.

I have managed to run py2exe and have my build and dist folders with my .exe inside. When I run my .exe I get some errors which I cannot resolve.

They point to modules which apparently do not exist, for example:

```
File "numpy\__init__.pyc", line 158, in <module>
```

When I look at the numpy__init__.py file in line 158 it points to

```
from . import core
```

So in my py2exe file I include the line:

```
opts = {
    'py2exe': { 
              'includes' : [ 'numpy.core']
```

But i still get this error.

Would it be because the version of numpy I am using is not compatible with the version of Python?

thanks

Comment: I also had troubles with py2exe and eventually I've never been able to use it (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45734926/build-a-exe-for-windows-from-a-python-3-script & co). I'm curious to see the answer to your questionning